# MySQL insert query if condition matches in after insert trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, insert

I'm using WampServer with MySQL Version: 5.7.9 and phpMyAdmmin Version: 4.5.2

I'm trying to write an after insert trigger on Table1 to insert data in Table2 if the data doesn't exist in Table2. Below is my query:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insert_customer`;
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_customer` AFTER INSERT ON `installations`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`phone` = NEW.`phone`) = 0
    THEN INSERT INTO `customers` (`phone`, `imei`, `platform`, `version_code`) VALUES (NEW.`phone`, NEW.`imei`, NEW.`platform`, NEW.`version_code`);
    END IF;
END;
```

This gives me the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

I've tried with delimiter too:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insert_customer`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_customer` AFTER INSERT ON `installations`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`phone` = NEW.`phone`) = 0
    THEN INSERT INTO `customers` (`phone`, `imei`, `platform`, `version_code`) VALUES (NEW.`phone`, NEW.`imei`, NEW.`platform`, NEW.`version_code`)
    END IF;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

This gives me the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
END' at line 5
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help?

Comment: And the errors they give are...?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've got it. The correct SQL is:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insert_customer`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_customer` AFTER INSERT ON `installations`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`phone` = NEW.`phone`) = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `customers` (`phone`, `imei`, `platform`, `version_code`) VALUES (NEW.`phone`, NEW.`imei`, NEW.`platform`, NEW.`version_code`);
    END IF;
END;|
DELIMITER ;
```

The ; at the end of my INSERT query solved my problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the extra delimiter; try changing

```
END;
|
```

to

```
END|
```

Comment: still getting the same error even after apply you suggestion. :(